# Changing pointer to a struct, passed by reference

Tags: c, struct

I have this call on a file called 'PlayBoard.c':

```
MoveSucc = putBoardSquare(theBoard, getX, getY, nextTurn);
```

Where 'theBoard' is a pointer to struct Board. Inside the function I am changing the board's size by referencing the pointer to ANOTHER Board struct, a bigger one. Will it change 'theBoard' on 'PlayBoard.c', where MoveSucc is invoked?

EDIT: putBoardSquare is defined in another source file

EDIT: I've added the relevant functions

```
Boolean putBoardSquare(BoardP theBoard, int X, int Y, char val)
{
    if (val != 'X' && val != 'O')
    {
        reportError(BAD_VAL);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (X<0 || Y<0)
    {
        reportError(OUT_OF_BOUND);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (X>theBoard->height || Y>theBoard->width)
    {
        theBoard = expandBoard(theBoard, X,Y);
    }

    printf("BOARD SIZE IS %d*%d\n",theBoard->height,theBoard->width);

    if (theBoard->board[X][Y] == 'X' || theBoard->board[X][Y] == 'Y' )
    {
        reportError(SQUARE_FULL);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (val != turn)
    {
        reportError(WRONG_TURN);
        return FALSE;
    }

    theBoard->board[X][Y] = val;
    printf("PUT %c\n",theBoard->board[X][Y]);
    changeTurn(val);

    return TRUE;
}

static BoardP expandBoard(ConstBoardP theBoard, int X, int Y)
{
    int newWidth = theBoard->width;
    int newHeight = theBoard->height;
    if (X>theBoard->height)
    {
        newHeight = (newHeight+1) * 2;
    }

    if (Y>theBoard->width)
    {
        newWidth = (newWidth+1) * 2;
    }

    BoardP newBoard = createNewBoard(newWidth,newHeight);
    copyBoard(theBoard,newBoard);
    printf("RETUNRNING NEW BOARD OF SIZE %d*%d\n",newHeight,newWidth);
    return newBoard;
}
```

As you can see, when the user tries to place 'X' or 'O' outside the board, it needs to be expanded which happens (I know cause I've printed new board's size in expandBoard() and in putBoardSquare()). But the pointer in 'PlayBoard.c' doesn't seem to change anyway....

My question: how can I change the pointer of a struct passed as an argument to another function? In 'PlayBoard.c' I pass one struct as an argument, and I want putBoardSquare to refrence it to another struct, which will take effect in PlayBoard.c as well.

Am I clear?

Comment: Please provide more relevant code. This question can't be easily answered in its current form.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it answered the wrong question, but the issue with the pointer not being updated is because you need a pointer to pointer for theBoard (assuming BoardP is a simple pointer).

Comment: Can you explain in more details? What do I need a pointer to pointer?
I thought that when you pass a pointer as a function argument, changing it will take effect outside the function as well

Comment: No, if you want to change where a pointer points to, you have to reference it through a pointer. I undelete my answer, see the example there.

Comment: @yotamoo changing the pointer doesn't have any effect. What does it changing data accessed through the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

```
theBoard = expandBoard(theBoard, X,Y);
```

This assignment only changes a local variable. You'll have to add one level of indirection, as in:

```
MoveSucc = putBoardSquare(&theBoard, getX, getY, nextTurn);

Boolean putBoardSquare(BoardP *theBoard, int X, int Y, char val)
{
    /* ... */
    *theBoard = expandBoard(theBoard, X,Y);
    /* ... */
}
```

---

Your question is confusing (perhaps you should post the code you have), but the error you have is cause simply by the definition of the struct not being available in `PlayBoard.c`. For instance, if you only have

```
struct foo;
void foo(struct foo *foov) { ... }
```

without a definition of foo available, as in

```
struct foo { int a; ... }
```

then you won't be able to access the members of the structure (see "opaque type").

Comment: But expandBoard return a pointer, so I can't do what you've offered.

Comment: @yot I don't understand your objection. You can't you? As far as I see, nothing has to change in `expandBoard`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you want to change where `theBoard` points to, you need to define it as a pointer to pointer, not as pointer.

```
MoveSucc = putBoardSquare(&theBoard, getX, getY, nextTurn);
```

and change the parameter in `putBoardSquare()` to `**` and when you set the pointer do it like (assuming `x` is a pointer):

`*theBoard = x;`